# How to implement "Share" button with GAE

Tags: api, google-app-engine, oauth, openid

I want to implement a "Share" button similar to Facebook´s "Like" button.

1. Is it possible to build an API on Google App Engine and allow users to login through 3rd party websites(after clicking on the "Share" button) to submit information to the API?
2. I want to prompt the user to select from multiple sign-in accounts when clicking on the "Share" button. Is there a way to prompt the user with the [OpenID selector](http://code.google.com/p/openid-selector/) on a 3rd party website? What other options are there to prompt the user with multiple sign-in accounts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes and its well documented.

Start here http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/overview.html#Authentication_Options

> App Engine does not provide a user interface API for OpenID sign-in. Your OpenID sign-in user interface must allow the user to enter a URL that serves as an OpenID identifier. You might also include a pop-up menu listing the domain names of popular OpenID providers, along with a box for the user to type the unique part of the URL. For more information on the user interface for OpenID sign-in, see [User Experience summary for Federated Login](http://sites.google.com/site/oauthgoog/UXFedLogin/summary).

2) In the text I quoted they mention that your site need to ask the user for a an URL that serves as an OpenID identifier. That is exactly what you could use openid-selector for. The  selector is a Javascript tool and runs on the client, not third party servers. You could have your share button bind the "onclick" event to open the selector.